# Closest Location SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, sql, location

Hey Guys I am looking for a way to calculate the closest location by querying a MYSQL database from a php page. So far I have a function in PHP that uses the Haversine formula to calculate the closest location, the only reason I did a PHP function was just to understand the formula itself. Now I am looking for a way to query a database which will contain lat and lon values for the closest location. I hope to do this by comparing a lat and long value on my php page with all the lat and long values in the database. I have been looking at [Googles tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html). But I do not really understand the sql query they are using.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) *
cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * 
sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
```

What does it mean by distance in the query ? Because I have tried using this query myself and it returned no results. IF anyone could help me understand this query it would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get results from mysql based on latitude longidude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528754/get-results-from-mysql-based-on-latitude-longidude)

Comment: Have you got any entries in your database? Are your database columns named the same (`lat` and `lng`) and are your latitude and longitude values correct? I've used that tutorial in the past myself and it's worked fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533140/near-location-search-on-google-maps-php-mysql/5533836#5533836

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was having was that I had '' characters for the field names e.g. cos( radians( 'lat' ) should of been cos( radians( lat )